# Titanium wifi event listenter change

Tags: connection, titanium, wifi

How can I have a listener that reports when connection is lost and when it comes back when app running forceground?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for that on `Ti.Network`.

```
Ti.Network.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  if(event.online){
    // online logic
  } else {
    // offline logic
  }
})
```

See the [Titanium docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-event-change) for more information you can get from the event. For instance if the connection is of type `Ti.Network.NETWORK_WIFI`.

Comment: Yes it working but if app running forceground more than 10 minute it will no action on 'change' listener,  it need to resume app again. can we make it event 'change' running all time?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Are you saying that after 10 minutes the `'change'` events are not fired anymore?

Comment: Yes i tested it. i saw it not respond Change events after i waiting 8 or 10 minutes. any solution ?